# How to check if a float is a whole number in Erlang?

Tags: floating-point, integer, erlang

I'm learning Erlang from [Learn You Some Erlang for great good!](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/) and as an exercise trying to implement a factorial function in Reverse Polish Notation calculator. So far I have this:

```
-module(rps).
-export([calculate/1]).

calculate(List) ->
  calculate(List, []).

calculate([], [ Number ]) ->
  Number;
calculate([ Head | Tail ], Stack) ->
  case Head of
    "+" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ A + B | Rest ]);
    "-" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ A - B | Rest ]);
    "*" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ A * B | Rest ]);
    "/" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ A / B | Rest ]);
    "!" ->
      [ A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ factorial(A) | Rest ]);
    _ ->
      calculate(Tail, [ Head | Stack ])
  end.

factorial(N) ->
  factorial(N, 1).

factorial(0, Accumulator) ->
  Accumulator;
factorial(N, Accumulator) when N >= 0  ->
  factorial(N - 1, Accumulator * N).
```

Now the problem is in my factorial/2 function, particularly the base case with `N = 0`. It works as expected as long as the first element on stack is an integer, e.g.:

```
5> rpcalc:calculate([1, 2, "+", "!"]).
6
```

However I've notice that division always returns a float, even if both arguments are integers and result is a whole number, e.g.:

```
7> 4 / 2.
2.0
```

So sometimes floats appear on my stack. Then, even if they are positive and whole numbers, my factorial fails, as `0.0 =/= 0`. The effect is:

```
13> rpcalc:calculate([6, 2, "/", "!"]).
** exception error: no function clause matching rpcalc:factorial(-1.0,0.0) (rpcalc.erl, line 33)
     in function  rpcalc:calculate/2 (rpcalc.erl, line 25)
```

What would be most elegant way to support positive whole floats here? My intuition is to have a case in `factorial/1` that would detect such numbers and cast them to integers, but maybe there is some better way?

Comment: If you work with area integer numbers then you can use corresponding operation, in this case - div. So  `"/" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      calculate(Tail, [ A div B | Rest ]);`.

Comment: Thanks. That may be part of the solution, but the problem is that it will always truncate the result. I do want to support floats in general and in case of fractions I want my factorial to throw. I just want `3.0 !` to produce `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more thought here is my own take on this:

```
factorial(N) ->
  factorial(float_to_integer(N), 1).

factorial(0, Accumulator) ->
  Accumulator;
factorial(N, Accumulator) when N >= 0  ->
  factorial(N - 1, Accumulator * N).

float_to_integer(N) when is_integer(N) ->
  N;
float_to_integer(N) when is_float(N) ->
  Integer = trunc(N),
  case N == Integer of
    true ->
      Integer;
    false ->
      error(badarg)
  end.
```

I've added a helper that I called `float_to_integer` that returns an integer for any whole number and throws an error otherwise. The name is a little misleading, as it can also handle integers. Then I use it to *guard* `factorial/1`.

Comment: good solution, but better use pattern matching and compare. Result `float_to_integer(N) when is_integer(N)->
  N;
float_to_integer(N)->
  Integer = trunc(N),
  case N == Integer of
    true ->
      Integer;
    false ->
      error(badarg)
  end.`

Comment: Btw,if you need review of your code which works, you can ask question on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you @Atomic_alarm. I've updated the code sample according to your advice.

Answer (score 2):

There exists `div` which takes integers and performs integer division. You can write it as:

```
calculate([], [ Number ]) ->
    Number;
calculate([ "+" | Tail ], [ B, A | Rest ]) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ A + B | Rest ]);
calculate([ "-" | Tail ], [ B, A | Rest ]) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ A - B | Rest ]);
calculate([ "*" | Tail ], [ B, A | Rest ]) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ A * B | Rest ]);
calculate([ "/" | Tail ], [ B, A | Rest ])
    when is_integer(A), is_integer(B), A rem B =:= 0 ->
    calculate(Tail, [ A div B | Rest ]);
calculate([ "/" | Tail ], [ B, A | Rest ]) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ A / B | Rest ]);
calculate([ "!" | Tail ], [ A | Rest ]) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ factorial(A) | Rest ]);
calculate([ Head | Tail ], Stack) ->
    calculate(Tail, [ Head | Stack ]).
```

Comment: Thanks. I made a small edit, as your original code was resulting in compilation error (`rpcalc.erl:20: variable 'A' is unbound
rpcalc.erl:20: variable 'B' is unbound
error`). Also, it does help in some cases by protecting against floats produced from division, but what about `rpcalc:calculate([2.0, 2, "+", "!"]).

Comment: @TadeuszŁazurski, just add several condition. For example `"/" ->
      [ B, A | Rest ] = Stack,
      if
        is_integer(A), is_integer(B), A rem B =:= 0 ->
            calculate(Tail, [ A div B | Rest ]);
        A==trunc(A),B==trunc(B)->
            calculate(Tail, [ trunc(A) div trunc(B) | Rest ]);
        true ->
            calculate(Tail, [ A / B | Rest ])
      end;`

Comment: @Atomic_alarm I think trying to prevent division from returning floats is not the best approach. If I add more operations, I will have to safeguard them as well. Also floats may come from the original input to `calculate/1`. Please take a look at my own answer and let me know what you think.

Comment: @TadeuszŁazurski: The error was introduced by the very non-Erlangish nature of your code. See my correction. It is idiomatic Erlang.

Comment: @TadeuszŁazurski There is _factorial_ functions for non-integers. They are Gamma and Pi function. See [Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this kind of pattern matching seems more *Erlangish*. As I said, I'm just beggining to learn the language, so thank you for pointing this. Still, I think the casting to integer should belong to `factorial` logic, not division.

Comment: @TadeuszŁazurski: You have to define how your _language_ should behave. It is up to you as an author.